# editText icons won't color when that field is pressed

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create a login activity with two fields - email and password. This is my activity XML where I implemented the 2 edit text labels. I want, when pressed, the icon from the edit text to change its color, but it seems that what I did doesn't work properly.

```xml
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/etLoginEmail"
        android:layout_width="375dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/custom_email_icon"
        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_input"
        android:paddingStart="12dp"
        android:paddingEnd="12dp"
        android:hint="Email"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/fredokamedium"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/logo" />

<EditText
        android:id="@+id/etLoginPass"
        android:layout_width="375dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/custom_lock_icon"
        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_input"
        android:paddingStart="12dp"
        android:paddingEnd="12dp"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/fredokamedium"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etLoginEmail" />
```

This is what i did for the custom icon xml files

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_lock_focused"/>

    <item android:state_focused="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_lock"/>
</selector>
```

Does anyone know what the issue may be?
[EditText-selected - shows border, but icon doesnt change color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/laFJg.png)

Comment: Can you please describe a bit more, what is going wrong? Maybe also add a screenshot of your current result.

Comment: So, my activity has two editTexts. One is for the email, one is for the password. I have done the custom icon xml (one for the email icon and one for the password icon) and the code is pasted a little bit up. When state_focused is true, i would like for the icon to be blue, and when not pressed, to be that ordinary grey. The issue is that when I press the editText, the icon does not change its color. I am not sure where I could paste a screenshot, I dont think it is possible in the comment ?

Comment: @cyberbrain I pasted a picture in the original question. Thank you.